# How to assign default user role in entrust?

Tags: php, authentication, web, laravel-5

I just want to assign a role to newly registered user. How I can achieve this in Laravel 5 with Entrust? I am using Entrust for roles and permissions.

Last time I tried to fire event after user registration in a file in vendor folder. Is there any way to fire an event for role assignment without modifying anything inside vendor folder?

If yes then where should I fire event? I don't want to modify anything inside my vendor folder like firing event in `postRegister()` in `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php` because new updates will overwrite my code.

Code on this link looks good but I don't know entrust has registration event or not.
http://laravel.io/forum/07-02-2014-entrust-assign-role-on-user-signup

Here is my code in routes.php:

```
// this event is firing on user login and i am getting user object
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user) {
   var_dump($user);
   die(__LINE__);
});

// this event is not firing on user registration
Event::listen('auth.register', function($user) {
   var_dump($user);
   die(__LINE__);
   //   $donor_role = DB::table('app_roles')->where('name', '=', 'donor')->pluck('id');
   //   $user->roles()->attach($donor_role);
   //   return false;
});
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out all by myself. Here is how I achieved:

I copied postRegister() function from **/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php** and overridden in **/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php** with some modification.

Here is the modified function in AuthController.php:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request) {
    $validator = $this->registrar->validator($request->all());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
        );
    }
    $this->auth->login($this->registrar->create($request->all()));
    // little modification :-)
    \Event::fire('auth.assign_default_role', $this->auth->user());
    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

And here is the event listener in routes.php:

```
Event::listen('auth.assign_default_role', function($user) {
    $donor_role = DB::table('app_roles')->where('name', '=', 'donor')- >pluck('id');
    $user->roles()->attach($donor_role);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Your solution gave me `Call to a member function roles() on null` on `routes.php`

Answer (score 3):

App\Service\Registrar.php
This is my way:

```
public function create(array $data)
    {
        $create = User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => $data['password'],
        ]);


        $user = User::find($create->id);

        $role = Role::where('name', '=', 'user')->firstOrFail();

        $user->roles()->attach($role->id);

        return $create;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fire the register event from your controller where the actual signup is being handled.

```
Event::fire('auth.register', array($user));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.7+ you can go to the `RegisterController` and modify the `create` function:

```
protected function create(array $data) {
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    $default_role = Role::where('name', 'DEFAULT_ROLE_NAME')->first();
    $user->attachRole($default_role);

    return $user;
}
```

Don't forget to `use App\Models\Role;` in the beginning.